# I got a problem with bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, windows

Hey guys I'm using mid 2013 MacBook Pro. I know how to install Windows from bootcamp and I already did last year.

Until now I haven't faced a problem like this: after creating an USB install disc I make a partition and Mac reboots when it reboots it stuck at white screen after I turn off the Mac with power button I start with option key it gives me 4 selection:

[image]

After selecting the volume Windows it stuck and I have to turn off with the power button. So does anyone know how to fix it ? Also I tried it with Windows 7 and Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

I would say start in recovery-mode (hold cmd + R on booting). My english is not the best but I'll try to explain:

You need a internet-connection and a (Time-Machine-)Backup of your whole data.

In the recovery-mode you have different utilities. You need the "Disk Utility". From there you delete your whole data.

Then you install from another utility (don't know the name) a new copy of the actual Mac OS X. Just migrate it with your backup and here you go.

The procedure with Windows you have to do again via Bootcamp, I don't know what you did this time and why it stucks.

Comment: I didn't delete mac as you can see the first disc is mac so I have mac os x the main problem is I can't install windows with bootcamp.

Comment: May your bootable usb is corrupt. Just format it and remake it via bootcamp to a bootable usb.